# Are there any static in-hand thinking procedures

Tags: discussion

I took exception to how broad this question was:

[Do you have any "in-hand" thinking procedures?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4204/do-you-have-any-in-hand-thinking-procedures)

To my mind, the question rather assumes the decisions are static throughout the hand, whereas for me, the decisions constantly change as the hand progresses.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a gray area. It's true that the kinds of decisions you make change through the course of a hand, but I think you could argue that the *process* itself can be static through a session. That process would combine your level of awareness of the game and the players at the table and their tendencies, but it would remain largely static for that given set of parameters. As your level of expertise with poker changes, you will change your approach and alter the process to include new information that you previously either weren't aware of or were unable to take advantage of. I think this kind of question is problematic in part because the question means something entirely differently to a new player than it would mean to an intermediate player, which would be different from what it means to an advanced player. Communication across these different boundaries of expertise is tricky sometimes.

Also, even if the process is static, it's such a big topic that it's not suitable for a single question here. The content of this question is basically the reason that any poker book that's ever been written has actually been written.